# dotnet build not showing StyleCop warnings that Visual Stuio does

Tags: visual-studio-2017, roslyn, stylecop, dotnet-cli

I've created a small project and added the [StyleCop.Analyzers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StyleCop.Analyzers/1.1.0-beta006) package (based on Roslyn). When I build in Visual Studio, I can see some warnings, which is what I expect.

However, when I build it using the dotnet CLI (`dotnet build`), I get no warnings. Just to be sure, I also tried using `msbuild`, which didn't produce any warnings either:

[image: StyleCop Analyzers]

So that has me wondering: what is the difference and how can I get the same result in both approaches?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because warnings do not stop the build from generating an assembly.  Visual Studio already built the assembly so when you call `dotnet build` or `msbuild` both see that there have been no changes and do not perform a build.  If you run `msbuild /t:rebuild` (run the rebuild target) you will see the warning on the commandline.

Below is what happens on my machine with Visual Studio 2017.6 and dotnet core 2.0:

```
C:\>dotnet new console -n stylcoptest
The template "Console Application" was created successfully.

Processing post-creation actions...
Running 'dotnet restore' on stylcoptest\stylcoptest.csproj...
  Restoring packages for C:\stylcoptest\stylcoptest.csproj...
  Generating MSBuild file C:\stylcoptest\obj\stylcoptest.csproj.nuget.g.props.
  Generating MSBuild file C:\stylcoptest\obj\stylcoptest.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
  Restore completed in 192.26 ms for C:\stylcoptest\stylcoptest.csproj.

Restore succeeded.

C:\>cd stylcoptest

>dotnet add package StyleCop.Analyzers --version 1.1.0-beta006
info : Adding PackageReference for package 'StyleCop.Analyzers' into project 'C:\stylcoptest\stylcoptest.csproj'
log  : Restoring packages for C:\stylcoptest\stylcoptest.csproj...
log  : Installing StyleCop.Analyzers 1.1.0-beta006.
info : Package 'StyleCop.Analyzers' is compatible with all the specified frameworks in project 'C:\stylcoptest\stylcoptest.csproj'
info : PackageReference for package 'StyleCop.Analyzers' version '1.1.0-beta006' added to file 'C:\stylcoptest\stylcoptest.csproj'

C:\stylcoptest> dotnet build
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.7.163.20755 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restore completed in 41.27 ms for C:\stylcoptest\stylcoptest.csproj.
Program.cs(1,1): warning SA1633: The file header is missing or not located at the top of the file. [C:\stylcoptest\stylcoptest.csproj]
Program.cs(3,11): warning SA1300: Element 'stylcoptest' should begin with an uppercase letter [C:\stylcoptest\stylcoptest.csproj]
Program.cs(1,1): warning SA1200: Using directive should appear within a namespace declaration [C:\stylcoptest\stylcoptest.csproj]
Program.cs(5,11): warning SA1400: Element 'Program' should declare an access modifier [C:\stylcoptest\stylcoptest.csproj]
Program.cs(7,21): warning SA1400: Element 'Main' should declare an access modifier [C:\stylcoptest\stylcoptest.csproj]
CSC : warning SA0001: XML comment analysis is disabled due to project configuration [C:\stylcoptest\stylcoptest.csproj]
  stylcoptest -> C:\Users\marol\Downloads\stylcoptest\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\stylcoptest.dll

Build succeeded.

Program.cs(1,1): warning SA1633: The file header is missing or not located at the top of the file. [C:\stylcoptest\stylcoptest.csproj]
Program.cs(3,11): warning SA1300: Element 'stylcoptest' should begin with an uppercase letter [C:\stylcoptest\stylcoptest.csproj]
Program.cs(1,1): warning SA1200: Using directive should appear within a namespace declaration [C:\stylcoptest\stylcoptest.csproj]
Program.cs(5,11): warning SA1400: Element 'Program' should declare an access modifier [C:\stylcoptest\stylcoptest.csproj]
Program.cs(7,21): warning SA1400: Element 'Main' should declare an access modifier [C:\stylcoptest\stylcoptest.csproj]
CSC : warning SA0001: XML comment analysis is disabled due to project configuration [C:\stylcoptest\stylcoptest.csproj]
    6 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:03.84

C:\stylcoptest>msbuild /m /v:m
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.6.85.37198 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  stylcoptest -> C:\stylcoptest\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\stylcoptest.dl

C:\stylcoptest>msbuild /m /v:m /t:rebuild
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.6.85.37198 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Program.cs(1,1): warning SA1633: The file header is missing or not located at the top of the file. [C:\stylcoptest\stylcoptest.csproj]
Program.cs(1,1): warning SA1200: Using directive should appear within a namespace declaration [C:\stylcoptest\stylcoptest.csproj]
Program.cs(5,11): warning SA1400: Element 'Program' should declare an access modifier [C:\stylcoptest\stylcoptest.csproj]
Program.cs(3,11): warning SA1300: Element 'stylcoptest' should begin with an uppercase letter [C:\stylcoptest\stylcoptest.csproj]
Program.cs(7,21): warning SA1400: Element 'Main' should declare an access modifier [C:\stylcoptest\stylcoptest.csproj]
CSC : warning SA0001: XML comment analysis is disabled due to project configuration [C:\stylcoptest\stylcoptest.csproj]
  stylcoptest -> C:\stylcoptest\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\stylcoptest.dll
```